# How to filter Legend to show only visible features?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.0, development, arcgis-engine

Is it possible to get the legend in a pagelayout to only show patches/swatches for features fall within the visible extent of the Map?

The solution needs to work on FeatureLayers and ArcGIS Server layer. It's possible to set a property on the [AutoVisibility](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/AutoVisibility_Property/00120000077n000000/) to filter the [Legend](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ILegend2_Interface/001200000776000000/) to only show the layers that are visible, but if the layer is visible and only a few of multiple symbols in the renderers is visible the legend gets too many items to be useful.

Update: This seems to be a question that has been asked several times before on the ESRI-forum, found one solution that seems to works on a FeatureLayer if it has a IUniqueValueRenderer [Compressing a legend to show displayed features only](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=62069&mc=7#158911) but we are using both FeatureLayer and ArcGIS Server layers, so that only solves part of our problem.

- We are trying to find a way to hide
  and show the IElement from ILegendItem.Graphics
  , but it feel like a deadend.
- On the server ILegendItem.Layer it 
  might be possible to cast to a 
  MapServerIdentifySublayer and use
  Identify to somehow find the visible 
  objects.

If that's possible its only a matter of connecting the two.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up trying to write my own and bought this instead.
http://www.spatial-online.com/LegendLimiterforArcGIS.htm

Comment: I've sent a question to NGIS http://www.ngis.com.au/Products/ArcGIS+Tools/default.aspx but mayby you know, does it work in ArcGIS Engine

Comment: The answer I got: "Unfortunately Legend Limiter doesn't work with ArcGIS Server layers. We do have a developers kit version of legend limiter that can be called from custom code however it isn't free."

Answer (score 1):

Last time I used LegendLimiter, it did not take into account Map Service layers and it was also only available for Desktop.  Things may have changed as this was good 3-4yrs back.